# Pyarrow.lib.Schema vs. pyarrow.parquet.Schema

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet, pyarrow

When I try to load across a many-partitioned parquet file, some of the schema get inferred invalidly because of missing data which fills the schema in with nulls. I would think specifying the schema in the pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset would fix this but I don't know how to construct a schema of the correct pyarrow.parquet.Schema type. Some example code:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pa.parquet as pq    
test_schema = pa.schema([pa.field('field1', pa.string()), pa.field('field2', pa.float64())])
paths = ['test_root/partition1/file1.parquet', 'test_root/partition2/file2.parquet']
dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(paths, schema=schema)
```

And the error:

```
AttributeError: 'pyarrow.lib.Schema' object has no attribute 'to_arrow_schema'
```

But I can't find any documentation on how to construct a pyarrow.parquet.Schema schema as in the docs (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.html) and have only made a pyarrow.lib.Schema which gives the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an API to construct a Parquet schema in Python yet. You can use one that you read from a particular file, though (see `pq.ParquetFile(...).schema`).

Could you open an issue on the ARROW JIRA project to request the feature to construct Parquet schemas in Python?

https://issues.apache.org/jira

Comment: Thanks, i will do that. But I tried a workaround creating my own wrapper class of a pyarrow schema with the to_arrow_schema function. So now I have a schema that I use to create a pyarrow table on which I call write_to_dataset. I use the same schema when call pq.ParquetDataset on the saved file but I get a ValueError: Schema in test_file.parquet was different. Is there anything I can do to fix this? I'm specifying the same schema on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

So thank you (whoever you are) if there was the ticket and fix in ARROW JIRA of this.

I was able to merge schemas of files in dataset and read dataset:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pa.parquet as pq

merged_schema = pa.schema([])

for filename in os.listdir(dataset_folder):
    schema_ = pq.read_table(os.path.join(dataset_folder, filename)).schema
    merged_schema = pa.unify_schemas([schema_, merged_schema])
```

Read dataset:

```
dset = pq.ParquetDataset(
           'my_dataset_folder', 
           schema=merged_schema,
           use_legacy_dataset=False
        ).read()
```

Comment: To improve on your solution: use pq.read_metadata to not read the entire table and then use to_arrow_schema() before unifying :)

Comment: Instead of pq.read_metadata I beleive pq.read_schema will work and doesn't need subsequent conversion as it reads the schema directly.